# .php file does not find file or directory of <link> or <script> html tags

Tags: php, html, forms, fullcalendar

Whenever I run my .php file on atom as "start in folder of current file" the FullCalendar link and script files cannot be found. This makes it so the calendar does not load. If I covert the file to .html, however, and preview HTML, the calendar does load and the files can be found. I am using PHP and sessions to transfer name information from my `index.php` file to `calendar.php` file.

This is the PHP Server logs:

```
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Sta
at line 0, file Unknownrtup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: C:\php\ext\bz2 (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_bz2.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: C:\php\ext\curl (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried: C:\php\ext\gd2 (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_gd2.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gettext' (tried: C:\php\ext\gettext (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_gettext.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unab
at line 0, file Unknownle to load dynamic library 'gmp' (tried: C:\php\ext\gmp (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_gmp.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: C:\php\ext\mbstring (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'exif' (tried: C:\php\ext\exif (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_exif.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: C:\php\ext\mysqli (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'odbc' (tried: C:\php\ext\odbc (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_odbc.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: C:\php\ext\openssl (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: C:\php\ext\pdo_mysql (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_odbc' (tried: C:\php\ext\pdo_odbc (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_pdo_odbc.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_pgsql' (tried: C:\php\ext\pdo_pgsql (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_pdo_pgsql.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: C:\php\ext\pdo_sqlite (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pgsql' (tried: C:\php\ext\pgsql (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_pgsql.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
at line 0, file Unknown[Fri Mar 22 17:08:22 2019] PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'shmop' (tried: C:\php\ext\shmop (The specified module could not be found.), C:\php\ext\php_shmop.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:24 2019] 127.0.0.1:50835 [200]: /calendar.php
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:24 2019] 127.0.0.1:50836 [404]: /packages/core/main.css - No such file or directory
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:24 2019] 127.0.0.1:50837 [404]: /packages/daygrid/main.css - No such file or directory
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:24 2019] 127.0.0.1:50838 [404]: /packages/timegrid/main.css - No such file or directory
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:24 2019] 127.0.0.1:50839 [404]: /packages/list/main.css - No such file or directory
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:24 2019] 127.0.0.1:50840 [404]: /packages/core/main.js - No such file or directory
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:24 2019] 127.0.0.1:50841 [404]: /vendor/rrule.js - No such file or directory
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:24 2019] 127.0.0.1:50842 [200]: /css/modalstyle.css
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:24 2019] 127.0.0.1:50843 [404]: /packages/timegrid/main.js - No such file or directory
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:24 2019] 127.0.0.1:50844 [404]: /packages/daygrid/main.js - No such file or directory
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:24 2019] 127.0.0.1:50845 [404]: /packages/list/main.js - No such file or directory
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:24 2019] 127.0.0.1:50846 [404]: /packages/rrule/main.js - No such file or directory
[Fri Mar 22 17:08:24 2019] 127.0.0.1:50847 [404]: /packages/interaction/main.js - No such file or directory
```

I am not sure if there is a better way to transfer information. Is it possible to not use PHP at all, and if so, how? I am fairly new to these topics, so please explain in detail with examples. Thanks!!

calendar.php code:

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />

  <!-- Modal display files-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/modalstyle.css">

  <!-- FullCalendar packages -->
  <link href='../packages/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='../packages/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='../packages/timegrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link href='../packages/list/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src='../vendor/rrule.js'></script>
  <script src='../packages/core/main.js'></script>
  <script src='../packages/interaction/main.js'></script>
  <script src='../packages/daygrid/main.js'></script>
  <script src='../packages/timegrid/main.js'></script>
  <script src='../packages/list/main.js'></script>
  <script src='../packages/rrule/main.js'></script>

  <script>
    var isShowAll = true;
    var thisOwner = "Pranay Agrawal";
    var calendar = null;
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      // TODO turn PHP variable into javascript?
      var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

      calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'rrule'],

        /*The bar on the top of the calendar for navigation*/
        header: {
          /*left: 'prev,next today',*/
          left: 'myEvents, today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'timeGridOneWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek',

        },
        customButtons: {
          myEvents: {
            text: 'My Events Only',
            click: function() {

            }
          }
        },

        /*Custom views*/
        views: {
          timeGridOneWeek: {
            type: 'timeGrid',
            duration: {
              days: 7
            },
            buttonText: 'week'
          },
          listWeek: {
            duration: {
              days: 7
            }
          }
        },

        /*Could be used to set certain times for some weeks*/
        /*businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
          {
            daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
            startTime: '08:00', // 8am
            endTime: '22:30' // 6pm
          },
          {
            daysOfWeek: [6, 7], // Thursday, Friday
            startTime: '10:00', // 10am
            endTime: '16:00' // 4pm
          }
        ],*/

        slotLabelInterval: {hours: 1}, //slots labeled by one hour
        selectOverlap: false, //user not allowed to "select" periods of times that are occupied by events
        defaultView: 'timeGridOneWeek', //start on week view
        slotDuration: '00:15:00', //each hour is split into 15 minutes
        minTime: "06:00:00", //start day 6am
        maxTime: '23:00:00', //end day 11pm
        scrollTime: '11:30:00', //start view at 11:30am?
        allDaySlot: false, //cannot make allday events
        nowIndicator: true, //red bar that shows current time
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        weekNumbersWithinDays: true, //styling week numbers in dayGrid view
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

        events: [{
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2019-02-01'
          },
          {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2019-02-07',
            end: '2019-02-10'
          },
          {
            groupId: 999,
            id: 2,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2019-02-09T16:00:00'
          },
          {
            groupId: 999,
            id: 2,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2019-02-16T16:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Conference',
            id: 2,
            start: '2019-02-11',
            end: '2019-02-13'
          },
          {
            title: 'Dunkin\' Donuts',
            start: '2019-03-17T10:30:00',
            end: '2019-03-17T11:15:00',
            color: '#800080'
          },
          {
            title: 'AppleBee\'s',
            start: '2019-03-22T15:00:00',
            end: '2019-03-22T16:30:00',
            location: 'The Arena',
            color: '#ff0000',
            //  rendering: 'background', (may be useful for add event, turn all events to invert background to show not available)
            description: 'Big Event',
            owner: 'Pranay Agrawal'
          },
          {
            title: 'Mellow Mushroom',
            start: '2019-03-19T13:30:00',
            color: '#cc3300'
          },
          {
            title: 'India Oven',
            start: '2019-03-20T16:30:00',
            color: '#cc9900'
          },
          {
            title: 'Thai Thai',
            start: '2019-03-21T12:00:00',
            color: '#669900'
          },
          {
            title: 'Birthday Party',
            start: '2019-02-13T07:00:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Click for Google',
            url: 'http://google.com/',
            start: '2019-02-24T12:05:00'
          },
          {
            title: 'Free Pizza',
            allday: 'false',
            borderColor: "#5173DA",
            color: '#99ABEA',
            location: '3rd Floor Boys',
            textColor: "#000000",
            description: "<p>This is just a fake description for the Free Pizza.</p><p>Nothing to see!</p>",
            start: '2019-03-23T12:05:00',
            end: '2019-03-23T12:55:00',
            owner: 'Jason Tran'
            //url:"http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/worst-job-titles-in-internet-and-info-tech/"
          }
        ],

      eventRender: function(info) {
        if(isShowAll) { //show all events
          return true;
        }
        else if(info.event.extendedProps.owner!=thisOwner) { //if an event is not the owner's, remove it from display!
          return false;
        }
      },

        eventClick: function(info) {
          //info.el.style.borderColor = 'red'
        //  window.alert(allEvents[2].title);
        //  window.alert(myEvents);

          /* Change modal html text dependent on event information*/
          document.getElementById("myTitle").innerHTML = info.event.title;
          document.getElementById("myLoc").innerHTML = info.event.extendedProps.location;
          document.getElementById("myDesc").innerHTML = info.event.extendedProps.description;
          document.getElementById("myTime").innerHTML = info.event.start + " - " + info.event.end;

          /* Functionality for displaying and removing modal on click*/
          var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
          var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
          modal.style.display = "block"; //show the modal display
          span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
          }
          window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
              modal.style.display = "none";
            }
          }

        }
      });
      calendar.render();
    });

  function myEventFunc() {

    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
      if (checkBox.checked == true){
        isShowAll=false;
      } else {
        isShowAll=true;
      }
    //  window.alert("myEventFunc called: " + isShowAll);
      calendar.rerenderEvents();

    }

  </script>

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 40px 10px;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    #calendar {
      max-width: 900px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    /* cursor pointer when hovering events */
    .fc-event,
    .fc-list-item {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .e1Div {
    color: #000;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);

    }

  </style>
</head>

<body>

<?php
  print_r($_SESSION);
?>
  <!-- <button class="e1Div" type="button" id="myCheck" onClick="myEventFunc()"/>
    My Events Only
  </button> -->

<div class="e1Div">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onClick="myEventFunc()" />
    <label for="e1">My Events Only</label>

</div>

  <div id='calendar'></div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h2 id='myTitle'>Modal Header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id='myTime'>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
        <p id='myDesc'>Some other text...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <h3 id='myLoc'>Modal Footer</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sounds like the PHP engine is not starting properly. I don't know atom so maybe there's something wrong with the way it is initialising it. Better to just run it in a normal webserver like Apache or something, unless you can get some guidance about how to integrate it with your IDE properly. Either way this doesn't sound like a code issue.

Comment: Ps. Other than printing the value from your session, you don't seem to be actually using PHP here much. All your calendar events are static data in the JavaScript. Are you intending to change it to read them from a database at some point, perhaps? Right now you're correct, you don't really need PHP...but a calendar containing preset static data isn't going to be a very useful tool. What are your plans?

Comment: And no, you don't have to use PHP as your server side language, there are lots of alternatives e.g. NodeJS, Asp.Net , python, perl, Java, you name it.

Comment: The project is a transportation website that will take in a logged user request, send to an admin for approval, and once approved will display on the calendar. The user will first login through gmail. If verified, the calendar will be displayed with events loaded from PHP or JSON. An optional button called "My Events Only" will appear at the top, and if clicked, will filter the events to only your events (working now).

Comment: I need a method to figure out what user is logged in so that the "My Events Only" button knows what events to filter. That was my purpose for using PHP, to communicate between my files the full name of the person logged in. These are my plans... I'm most familiar with Java, but how do I use that in terms of server-side language to communicate between my .html pages? Or am I making this entire process way to complicated when a more simple solution exists?

Comment: Java Server Pages is the framework you use if you want to use Java as the back end, as far as I know. And so far no you don't see to have made it over complicated.